# Rails 2.3.5 I18n month/day name translation problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

My `config/locales/pl.yml` file (sampled from [here](http://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/pl.yml)):

```
pl:
  date:
    day_names: [Niedziela, Poniedziałek, Wtorek, Środa, Czwartek, Piątek, Sobota]
    month_names: [~, Styczeń, Luty, Marzec, Kwiecień, Maj, Czerwiec, Lipiec, Sierpień, Wrzesień, Październik, Listopad, Grudzień]
```

In `script/console`:

```
I18n.locale = 'pl'
=> "pl"

Time.now.strftime("%A, %B")
=> "Tuesday, August"
```

Why? Or put it another way - how can I get translated month names? I'll also note that the locale file is definitely read as it includes a bunch of other translations, which all work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That depends on which rails version you are using.
There's a helper to translate that, on rails 3.0.0 (I don't know from which version it was made available).

In a view, you can write

```
localize Time.now, :format => '%A, %B'
```

in script/console (or rails console), try typing:

```
controller.localize Time.now, :format => '%A, %B'
```

and see if it works.
There's also the `l`helper (lowercase L), which is a shorthand for `localize`:

```
controller.l Time.now, :format => '%A, %B'
```

Comment: Thanks! It's all about using `localize` instead of `translate` helper. Btw, in console (in Rails 2.3) it should be `helper.localize Time.now, :format => "%B"`, not `controller.`. And another addition - you must have `pl, time, formats` entries in `pl.yml`.